# Unable to read body returned by HTTPoison

Tags: http, elixir

I have this:

```
HTTPoison.start
case HTTPoison.get("some url") do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    IO.puts(body)
```

Which produces an exception:

```
Generated escript grex_cli with MIX_ENV=dev
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :io.put_chars(#PID<0.49.0>, :unicode, [<<60, 33, 100, 111,..... 58, ...>>, 10])
    (elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:76: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2
```

How can I read the body and print it?

Comment: Looks like invalid UTF-8. Try `IO.inspect(body)`. Does that URL return a binary file?

Comment: @Dogbert, text. now it returns `<<60, 33, 100, 111, 99.....` How can I decode that to a text?

Comment: `<<60, 33, 100, 111, 99>> #=> "<!doc"` looks like you're fetching an HTML page? That page seems to have invalid UTF-8 content somewhere. Would it be possible to share the actual URL? In any case, if you just want to write that to the terminal, you can do `IO.binwrite(body)`.

Comment: @Dogbert, I want to parse it. How can I decode it to a text to be able to parse, will `binwrite` work for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" here? Are you going to use some Elixir/Erlang HTML Parser library? Something else? `IO.binwrite` will just let you write the body to a file or stdout and fix the original problem in the question that `IO.puts` doesn't print the body.

Comment: @Dogbert, by parse I mean to find substrings. right, but that wasn't my  goal, that was a subtask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IO.puts` fails with that error because `body` here is not valid UTF-8 data. If you want to write non UTF-8 binary to stdout, you can use `IO.binwrite` instead of `IO.puts`:

```
IO.binwrite(body)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I got compressed content.

So I unzipped it before printing:

```
IO.puts :zlib.gunzip(body)
```

You also can check if body is compressed before `unzip`: https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/81#issuecomment-219920101