# Output a non UTF-8 in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I was playing with the HTTPoison library and when I tried to output google's homepage, I got what seems to be an encoding error:

```
HTTPoison.start
response = HTTPoison.get!("https://www.google.com")
IO.puts response.body
** (ArgumentError) argument error
(stdlib) :io.put_chars(#PID<0.50.0>, :unicode, [<<60, 33, 100, 111, 99, 116, 121, 112, 101, 32, 104, 116, 109, 108, 62, 60, 104, 116, 109, 108, 32, 105, 116, 101, 109, 115, 99, 111, 112, 101, 61, 34, 34, 32, 105, 116, 101, 109, 116, 121, 112, 101, 61, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, ...>>, 10])
```

Looking at the HTTP headers, it seems that google is sending iso-8859-1. Can't seem to find a good, straight-forward answer for how to deal with this. All I want is to output the result.

For what it's worth:

- I'm using erlang 19.1 and elixir 1.3.4.
- I tried with other HTTP libraries and I get the same result
- Super new to Elixir, here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read body returned by HTTPoison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155304/unable-to-read-body-returned-by-httpoison)

Comment: Short answer: use `IO.binwrite`. More info in my answer to the question I linked above as a duplicate.

Comment: you're absolutely right!